# Implementing feature selection

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, anomaly-detection

One problem I came across when trying to predict with a feature selected data set, is that once you have selected certain features, if you were to predict on the test data set, the test data set features would not align because the training data set would have less features due to feature selection. How do you implement feature selection properly such that the test data set would have the same features as the training data set?

Example:

```
 from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
 from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
 from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
 iris = load_iris()
 X, y = iris.data, iris.target
 X.shape
(150, 4)
 X_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k=2).fit_transform(X, y)
 X_new.shape
(150, 2)
```

Comment: You have to `transform` your testing set too... And *dont* use `fit_transform`, but just `transform`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga My only concern is when implementing the feature selection on the test data set, is there a possibility of attaining different set of features from that of the training data set?

Comment: You *don't* feature select on the test data for that very reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `transform` your testing set too... And *dont* use `fit_transform`, but just `transform`. This requires you to save your `SelectKBest` object, so something to the effect of:

```
selector = SelectKBest(chi2, k=2)
X_train_clean = selector.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
X_test_clean = selector.transform(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to create a feature_selector object by fitting with `SelectKBest` first and then `transform` your test data. Like so:

```
feature_selector = SelectKBest(chi2, k=2).fit(X_train, y)
X_train_pruned = feature_selector.transform(X_train)
X_test_pruned = feature_selector.transform(X_test)
```